# attached image pointers regarding querying a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please have a look at the image link to understand my scribbling in the question.

A table has users from different states of Australia who used different methods to approach the application.

This table has column for userids `[id]`(1,2,3,4,5,6..14000),  column `approaches` (a,b,c,d,e,f)  and column `states` (wa,vic..)

Now I need to formulate a table which would have columns with column#1 as  `approaches` and remaining column names with states names like westernaustralia, victoria, SA,queensland etc.

The approach 'a' row would have total no of people who used this approach in different states victoria 5 wa 0

And in the same way other 5 approaches would have number of people used the approach in different states(in columns).

(eg: approach 'b' row- vic 3 wa 1 sa2...etc)

Here's the link for the image please have a look at it .https://i.stack.imgur.com/DldhT.png

Comment: "Hope I made it clear.." - No, you did not.

Comment: Add the sample data and expected result in table format

Comment: sure.I edited the question though.

Comment: Still you did not do justice to this last line *Hope I made it clear* :D

Comment: YUPsorry about that. .  I ATTACHED the Link. Now, it should be clear have a look and let me know if you could give me any suggestion. :)

Comment: Still not a very clear question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a PIVOT statement like below.

```
create table data (id int, [state] nvarchar(100), approaches nvarchar(10));
insert into data values
(1,'nsw','a'),
(2,'','b'),
(3,'wa','c'),
(4,'qld','d');

select 
   approaches,
   [New South Wales]=[nsw],
   [Western Australia]=[wa],
   [Queensland]=[qld],
   [Victoria]=[vic],
   [South Australia]=[sa],
   [not available]
from 
(
    select 
       id,
       case 
           when [state] ='' then 'not available' 
           else [state]
       end as [state],
       approaches
    from data
)src
pivot
(
 count(id) for [state] in ([nsw],[wa],[qld],[vic],[sa],[not available])   
)p
```

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/XEXEU12447)**</kbd>